# How to convert sql cursor output to spark dataframe in spark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I got an output using `cursor.fetchall()`.

How can I convert the output into Spark dataframe and create a parquet file in Pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [JDBC connection](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) to connect Spark with your database

Comment: But how will i create dataframe..returned from fetchall

Comment: if you look at the link I sent, you will see an example of loading data from JDBC to dataframe **natively**. You do not converting from fetchall to dataframe, that's the wrong approach